# Update database using strongly typed DataSet

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a database with SQL Server 2014. I made a stored procedure that selects several fields. Until then everything is fine. It returns a `DataTable` that I bind with my `DataGridView`. The problem is when I want to update that `DataTable`. I made another stored procedure for the update. (My update works fine in SQL Server). For some reason when I do the update from Visual Basic, it updated my `DataSet` but not my database! For some reason, it looks like it does not connect to the database.

I know i can use `SqlConnection.Open()` and `SqlConnection.Close()` but I'm working with the "Disconnected Ado.net" so when i call the `UpdateCommand`, it's supposed to connect directly to the database, but it didn't! What am i doing wrong?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Here is a part of my code:

```vb
'Initialize my command
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
command.CommandText = "dbo.update"

command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@idInventory", SqlDbType.Int, 1, table.Columns(0).Caption))
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@idProduct", SqlDbType.Int, 1,    table.Columns(1).Caption))
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
command.Parameters("@code").SourceColumn = "code"

command.Connection = adaptater.Connection

Try
    adaptater.Adapter.UpdateCommand = command
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Not sure but you have a syntax issue with your command parameters add area. You are missing a period in one of them...

Comment: How many statements in your SP? Does it do anything else besides updating 1 table? If your answer is `No` than you wasting your time. You can use data adapter to run update statement on your `DataTable` on changed rows.

Comment: In the code you have shown, you don't actually execute the command. [Also, you've tagged this with 'strongly-typed dataset' but you are using the weakly-typed model.]

Comment: Yes, my SP update actually 2 tables. And peterG, what do you mean? ExecuteNonQuery() command doesnt work. Is it an other command?

Comment: Your 'execute' doesn't appear in the code you've shown. And if you are updating using a SP, how does that update the dataset? In fact, you've not shown us the dataset either. Using a strongly-typed dataset, you'd typically bind the dataset to the grid via a BindingSource, and then use a TableAdapter to perform your SELECT and UPDATE queries.

Comment: Personally I'd use a completely different approach - I'd split off the database stuff into a separate Data Access Layer, which would return an invoice object containing a list of invoice lines. I'd bind the grid to this list.  The DAL would then also be responsible for the update. This unties the connection between your database code and your UI code and gives you a lot more flexibility.